# Creating an Azure VM image with packer

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-machine, packer

I am trying to create an Azure VM image using packer. My packer template looks like this

```
variable "version" {
  type = string
  default = "1.0.0"
}

variable "created_by" {
  type = string
}

source "azure-arm" "development_subscription" {
  azure_tags      = {
    CreatedBy     = var.created_by
    CreatedDate   = formatdate("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss",timestamp())
  }
  image_offer                       = "WindowsServer"
  image_publisher                   = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
  image_sku                         = "2022-datacenter-g2"
  managed_image_name                = "MyImage_${var.version}"
  managed_image_resource_group_name = "Some-RG"
  os_type                           = "Windows"
  location                          = "ukwest"
  # client_id       = var.client_id
  # client_secret   = var.client_secret
  subscription_id                   = "e8204745-e84f-4b2e-9e6f-545656fe0922"
  vm_size                           = "Standard_D2s_v3"
  winrm_insecure  = true
  winrm_timeout   = "20m"
  winrm_use_ssl   = true
  winrm_username  = "packer"
}
```

However I keep on getting:

```
==> azure-arm.development_subscription: Waiting for WinRM to become available...
==> azure-arm.development_subscription: Timeout waiting for WinRM.
```

Other resources I've found online imply I should try increasing the timeout, but this VM doesn't seem likely to take longer than a few seconds to boot. Do I need to do something to disable the system firewall?

Comment: For Packer+Azure+Windows+WinRM, you normally also need to specify the `winrm_password` argument. I also have not seen `packer` as a valid `winrm_username` argument for that image before.

Comment: @MattSchuchard specifying a password doesn't resolve the issue, but it does allow me to start experimenting with trying to log into PS remoting outside of packer, so many thanks!. PS remoting has yielded some interesting results around certificate validity. I'll keep digging on this topic and update once I've found something out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing `tenant_id`. Once I added that, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code  it also got stuck while connecting to ***`winRM`*** and timed out waiting for the same .

The ***Major issue*** I found in your code is that you have not added a `communicator ="WinRM"` . So ,For that reason the `WinRM` port doesn't get open and you are not able to connect through it.

So, I added the same as solution in the below code :

```
variable "version" {
  type    = string
  default = "1.0.0"
}

variable "created_by" {
  type    = string
  default = "ajay"
}
variable "client_secret" {
  default = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
variable "client_id" {
  default = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}

source "azure-arm" "development_subscription" {
  azure_tags = {
    CreatedBy   = var.created_by
    CreatedDate = formatdate("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss", timestamp())
  }
  image_offer                       = "WindowsServer"
  image_publisher                   = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
  image_sku                         = "2022-datacenter-g2"
  managed_image_name                = "MyImage_${var.version}"
  managed_image_resource_group_name = "ansumantest"
  os_type                           = "Windows"
  location                          = "ukwest"
  client_id                         = var.client_id
  client_secret                     = var.client_secret
  subscription_id                   = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  vm_size                           = "Standard_D2s_v3"
  communicator                      = "winrm"
  winrm_insecure                    = true
  winrm_timeout                     = "20m"
  winrm_use_ssl                     = true
  winrm_username                    = "packer"
}

build {
  name = "learn-packer"
  sources = [
    "source.azure-arm.development_subscription"
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, all I needed to do was add `tenant_id`.